# Google charts animated bar

Tags: javascript, animation, charts, google-api

I can not animate the google chart bar.
I looked at the sample documents, but I failed.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['table']});
    
  function drawBarFormatTable() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Department');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Revenues');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Depat');
    data.addRows([
      ['Shoes', 1.98,'deneme'],
      ['Sports', -2.3,'deneme'],
      ['Toys', 3.4,'deneme'],
      ['Electronics', -0.2,'deneme'],
      ['Food', 2,'deneme'],
      ['Art', 2.5,'deneme']
    ]);

    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('barformat_table'));
    
    var formatter = new google.visualization.BarFormat({width: 250});
    
    formatter.format(data, 1); // Apply formatter to second column
    table.draw(data, {allowHtml: true, showRowNumber: true, width: '100%', height: '100%'});
  }

  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBarFormatTable);
```

```html
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <div id="barformat_table" style="height: 150px"/>
```

work here: https://jsfiddle.net/wqL5rLcg/

Comment: the `Table` chart doesn't support animation -- you could use a [`BarChart`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#examples) instead...